# Sublime Text 3 - Create a key bind for "Save All"?

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

I recently downloaded Sublime Text 3 (Build 3083) and I would like to create a Key Binding for "Save All" (File -> Save All), but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible?

My preferred key for "Save All" is 'F9'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked around and found an alternative solution to my issue:
instead of "Save All" I could use "Build" (Tools -> Build) (Ctrl+B).

There's an option to "Save all on Build" (Under Tools), if I check that option I can then re-bind the hotkey for Build like so:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "build" }
```

(I chose 'ctrl+s' instead of 'F9')

This works well enough for me, so problem solved.

Comment: You can use **command save_all instead of build** if you want.

Comment: Yea, that works nicely. I think I'll use that instead. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think adding line in **Preference.sublime.settings --- User** will be better.

```
"save_on_focus_lost": true,
```

This will set true to automatically save files when switching to a different file or application